# Is there a oficial plugin or SDK to use MercadoPago in React-Native for iOS?

Tags: react-native

The problem here is that I need call *MercadoPago* in mi Application using React-Native, but i can not find the way,

I found this wrapper for use in React-Native,
 https://github.com/shovelapps/react-native-mercadopago

but when I am trying to call it I have an error in startCheckOut method, 
I am using in this way the Wrapper

```
import RNMercadopago from 'react-native-mercadopago';
```

and I am calling the method in a click event using this line:

```
RNMercadopago.startCheckout(publicKey, prefId, null, false, (payment) => { this._success(payment)}, (error) => { this._failure(error) });
```

but I am getting the bellow error,

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNMercadopago.startCheckout)
```

all this code is in the index.ios.js

best regards

Answer (score 0):

you may use [react-native-mercadopago-checkout](https://github.com/BlackBoxVision/react-native-mercadopago-checkout). It allows you to implement MercadoPago checkout in two diferent ways (both of them are documented).
It's a new implementation that is working in a production app. Even, if you find a bug, you could open an Issue and be sure that it will be resolved!